# Uncaught Error: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'Y.props.navigation') touchableHandlePress@[native code]

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation, expo, react-navigation-drawer

I'm adding in the react-navigation header a drawerMenuButton to open the Drawer Menu.

The icon appears normally but when pressed returns the error quoted.

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, Dimensions } from 'react-native';
import { Button, Icon } from 'native-base';
import { createAppContainer, createStackNavigator, createDrawerNavigator } from 'react-navigation';
...

const DrawerConfig = {
  drawerWidth: Dimensions.get('window').width * 0.75,
  contentComponent: ({ navigation }) => {
    return(<MenuDrawer navigation={navigation} />)
  }
}

const HomeNavigator = createStackNavigator ({
...
}, {
  defaultNavigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => {
    return {
      headerTitleStyle: {
        fontWeight: 'bold'
      },
      headerLeft: (
        <Button transparent onPress={() => this.props.navigation.toggleDrawer()}>
          <Icon name='menu' style={{color: '#FFF'}} />
        </Button>
      ),
      headerRight: (
        <HomeIcon navigation={navigation} />
      ),
      headerStyle: {
        backgroundColor: '#b80003'
      },
      headerTintColor: '#FFF'
    }
  }
});

const DrawerNavigator = createDrawerNavigator (
  {
    'Principal': {
      screen: HomeNavigator
    },
    'Sobre o Aplicativo': {
      screen: InformationApp
    },
    'Sobre os Responsáveis': {
      screen: Team
    },
    'Sobre o Projeto': {
      screen: Project
    },
    'Política e Termos': {
      screen: Policy
    }
  },
  DrawerConfig
);

const AppDrawerContainer = createAppContainer(DrawerNavigator);

export default AppDrawerContainer;
```

It is important to note that for screens belonging to `const DrawerNavigator = createDrawerNavigator` I am using the same code above to render drawerMenuButton and it is working normally, the error occurs only on `const screens HomeNavigator = createStackNavigator`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Change your code like this

```
onPress={() => navigation.toggleDrawer()}>
```